# How to determine goodness-of-fit between non-parametric 2d-datasets

Tags: nonparametric, goodness-of-fit, agreement-statistics, 2d

Lets say I have a set of paired x' and y' values and I have a N sets of reference values also consisting of paired x and y values. I would like to determine which reference set best matches by x'y' set. The values in x and y are discrete and I have no parametric representation of any of the data. There maybe multiple x values with different y values in each set. The number of xy pairs in each refence set is not the same as the others. The x values in each of the refence sets are not the same. The x values are all bounded and the y values are all bounded. Any suggestions on how to determine which reference data set best fits my data set?

Example:

| x' | y' |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 5 |

| x1 | y1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 |

| x2 | y2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 9 | 4 |

| x3 | y3 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 |

Comment: This seems to be a question about agreement. I added the tag!